# Getting google chrome window title

Tags: c#, google-chrome, process

So I was trying to figure out how to get the Text/Title of the google chrome browser. I finally got to this, which looked promising..

```
cur_url = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")[0].MainWindowTitle;
```

cur_url is a string which will old the name. Sadly this does not work. it just returns a blank value. Is this the correct way to do this? Or is there another, more efficient way?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when there are multiple instances of the browser running? Or multiple tabs? Which title do you want to retrieve?

Comment: Even if When single instance of "Google Chrome" runs it opens up multiple instances of "chrome.exe" [See Image](http://i.imgur.com/22dZw.png)..So, this way it wont work! You cant know which instance is the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this answer:

[Get chrome browser title using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958051/get-chrome-browser-title-using-c-sharp/16958798#16958798)

It will work for you. you need to use Win32Api for this.