# Cannot update Process variable

Tags: c#, google-chrome, process

I'm trying to kill a process, but I can't bind a value to the process variable. This is what I got for my code;

```
URL = (string)result[1];
Process browser = Process.Start(@"chrome.exe","http:\\www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + URL);
Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 15);

resultaat = (string)result[2];
Videolengte = Convert.ToInt32(resultaat);
Tijd = Videolengte;
Tijd = 10;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Tijd);
browser = GetWindowProcess((string)result[3]);
//wanneer timer van het nummer weer klaar is, volgende dingen uitvoeren.
Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 15);
browser.Kill();
deleteRow();
```

GetWindowProcess

```
 private Process GetWindowProcess(string windowTitle)
    {
        foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
        {
            if (proc.MainWindowTitle.IndexOf(windowTitle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
            {
                return proc;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

It says browser is null when I try to kill it while I binded a processname to it, does anyone know the cause of this?

Comment: Do you see chrome.exe in the task manager?

Comment: Yes, i see it running.

Comment: And what is GetWindowProcess? I Googled that and found nothing.

Comment: Do you need to reset the browser variable? Surely you can just all .kill on the original Process returned from Process.Start?

Comment: @Francis Ducharme Sorry should've included it, GetWindowProcess is a Process that return s all chrome processes,         `private Process GetWindowProcess(string windowTitle)
        {
            foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
            {
                if (proc.MainWindowTitle.IndexOf(windowTitle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
                {
                    return proc;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }`

Comment: I'm looking for something to just kill all the chrome processes, when i call the browser.kill

Comment: Then create a method that does somewhat what GetWindowProcess does and do proc.Kill

Comment: Can you add GetWindowProcess to the code in the question please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is inside GetWindowProcess. When you perform `proc.MainWindowTitle`, it's returning an empty string for each process - Probably because the Chrome windows don't have titles, and the Tabs are not considered "windows"

Take a look at this answer to the same question elsewhere. It looks like it's been this way for a good few months at least...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16958798/2505574

If, according to your comments on this answer (which *isn't* what you are saying in your question), you want to kill **all** chrome processes, then you just need to write a method that iterates the processes and kills them:

```
public void KillChromeProcesses()
{
  foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcessByName("chrome"))
  {
    proc.Kill();
  }
}
```

Comment: But it used to work before, due to something changed it doesn't detect it properly again.. Can't seem to figure out what

Comment: Chrome have probably changed something that is stopping your code working. If I find an alternative method, I'll update the answer.

Comment: But that isn't my problem, i just want to kill all of the chrome tabs, the window title is just here for info which ones are open.

Comment: Then why is your code checking it and only returning a single process that matches your criteria?

Comment: nvm, ill just search for it myself.

Comment: The window title is useless in this case. Why do you want to know "which ones are open" if you plan to kill them all ?