# Getting specified tab from chrome and modifying it C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, process, html-parsing

**What i expect to get:**
Get specified tab from chrome process (example: "Google Translate") and parse content of this page (also availability to modify it).

*It only should be from already opened by user chrome window (not from web drivers or smth like that).*

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: @john, I've tried to do as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958051/get-chrome-browser-title-using-c-sharp but unsuccessfully...